# JPA how to annotate generic entity field conditionally?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have this generic entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Position<T> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private T name;
}
```

But there's a case where the generic type is a `String`:

```
@Entity
class ChildPosition0 extends Position<String> {
}
```

And, JPA will complaint that `String` is not an `enum` in this case, but I need to annotate this `name` field if it's an enum, if not, the database will mark it as `int` type, and that's not ideal. How do I solve this? How to annotate the field conditionally?

### My workaround:

Use `Position` as a parent class, and adding those field in child class individually, even though they share the same field:

```
@MappedSuperclass
abstract class Position {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
}
```

And extends it from child entity like this:

Child1:

```
@Entity
public class ChildPosition1 extends Position {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Priority name; // <- Priority is enum type
}
```

Child2:

```
@Entity
public class ChildPosition2 extends Position {

    private String name;
}
```

This is too ugly IMO. And Java does not allow class field override from child class. So, back to the question: how to annotate generic field conditionally?

Comment: If you look at this from a database perspective, where entity 'Position' data goes into table 'Position', how can generic types work? The type has to be set to be usable for queries and for schema validation for each row in the table, so what you are trying to do doesn't fit within an Entity.

Comment: @Chris Hi, thanks for pointing out the mistake. I'm sorry, I wasn't very clear about the question itself, `Position` only serves as parent class, not intended to save as an entity here, I've updated the question, so, feel free to take a look, I'm looking forward to hear more from you!

Comment: Now that you've shown Position as an abstract MappedSuperclass, you've still got the same problem though - any annotations you apply to that 'generic' property are only applicable to certain situations. What you want is a feature that isn't part of the spec; a way to tell it what to use and when. That currently only exists in JPA on the property on a per property basis. Alternatively, you can map this via XML: Have the generic type and all other annotations in your class but override this mapping in each class via XML files.